# Pause and resume while recording audio

Tags: android

In my app, I record voice and play it successfully. I need to pause the recording and the resume on button clicks. Any suggestions.

Comment: Notably absent from this question is a question.  What's the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: @user718861: If you are using the AudioRecord class, simply call stop() in order to 'pause' it so it no longer adds samples to its buffer. Then use startRecording() to 'resume' BUT before you resume read everything in it's buffer and discard the data.

Comment: I need as a combined audio file of both the files before and after resume. But it contains only the content after resume. pls any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do this with MediaRecorder, as far as I know. You'll just have to resume to a new file. If using Audio Recorder and streaming to a wave file, you can just open back the same file and seek to the end. Don't forget to update the header when you close the file.